# android - set both class and action for intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an Intent that I initiate like this:

```
notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
```

This intent is attached to an ongoing notification.

Now, in addition to the class opened when clicking the intent, I want to add an **action string** to the intent, so that when the notification clicked my custom `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to the same **action string** will trigger.

```
notificationIntent.setAction(context.getString(R.string.notification_clicked_action_string));
```

Problem is, for some reason, the `BroadcastReceiver` is not called, and I have other `BroadcastReceiver` that I registered problematically like this and they work fine.

So, it is a problem to have both a **class** and an **action** in an intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, it is a problem to have both a class and an action in an intent?

No, that is perfectly fine.

However, unless you have a very strange naming system, `HomeActivity` is an activity. That means that `new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class)` identifies that activity, and you are hopefully using that with `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. You cannot have a `BroadcastReceiver` respond to `startActivity()`, which is what will be called when the `PendingIntent` is invoked.

Comment: ohh I see, so is there any way to send a broadcast when clicking the notification?

Comment: @OfekAgmon: Sure. Use an `Intent` that matches the `BroadcastReceiver`, then use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. What you *can't* do is have a *single* `PendingIntent` that invokes both an activity and a receiver. You could have your activity send the broadcast in `onCreate()`, though.